# Ghusl'shower' after sex in ramadan

Tags: nikah

As a married couple we are allowed to have sex at night in Ramadan. So do we need to have ghusl before fajr or it is ok to have russal anytime.
 Please provide with proof if possible.

Comment: What is russal?

Comment: side note: ghusl is near to bathing not taking shower

Answer (score 1):

It's OK you can delay Ghusl (Showering) after the Fajr **`Azan`**.

The proof:

> 'A’isha and Umm Salamah (RAA) narrated, The Messenger of Allah (sallahu alayhi wasallam) would rise in the morning (when it is already Fajr time) while he was Junub (in a state of major ritual impurity due to intercourse) on a day in Ramadan. He would then perform Ghusl and fast. Agreed upon. In the narration of Muslim on the authority of Umm Salamah, ‘And he would not make up for it (that day).’
>
> وَعَنْ عَائِشَةَ وَأُمِّ سَلَمَةَ رَضِيَ اَللَّهُ عَنْهُمَا { أَنَّ
>   اَلنَّبِيَّ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-كَانَ يُصْبِحُ جُنُبًا مِنْ
>   جِمَاعٍ, ثُمَّ يَغْتَسِلُ وَيَصُومُ } مُتَّفَقٌ عَلَيْهِ 1‏ .‏
>
> [ [<sub>Bulugh al-Maram, Book 5, Hadith 698</sub>](http://sunnah.com/urn/2108200) ]